# Getting a user personal details through JS

Tags: javascript, security

Is there anyway a site I am using that runs a JS script (or any other script for that matter) can know my Facebook ID?

i.e., If I am logged in to facebook (on a different window, but I do have an active session) and I open another browser window, is there anyway the site in the new window can run some sort of a script and get my facebook ID?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: no, there is no way. would you want that if your logged into facebook on one tab and all your other tabs could just get all your information from the other page

Comment: Sure i wouldn't, thats why I am curious to know

Comment: @red-x i am still curious.. all of my profile info is just a button click away.. (facebook Oauth) when we sign into a site, we just have to click 'allow' is there any way through javascript that can mimic that button click..? i know it is possible to click a button on form with js but sure is not as simple as a submitting a form.. right?

Comment: @Achshar submitting a form with js is even easier than mimicking a mouseclick, however since this is another domain you don't have js access and it would be considered an XSS(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack.

Comment: @red-X what about iframes? what if it opens the facebook oauth page in an iframe? i guess js can access in iframe's contents right?

Comment: @Achshar, nope, you'll run into a JS error if its another domain. you can access an iFrame's content if its the same domain though.

Comment: ohkeezz thanks for clearing thing out for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they can't, that kind of information is domain binded.